# Self hosted fonts not working with Vite React and Tailwind CSS

Tags: tailwind-css

I have a Vite React.js project where I use Tailwind with it, I want to use self hosted fonts, I used a lot of methods but none of them worked.

I have made this sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/vite-react-and-tailwind-self-hosted-fonts-vlc2g9

when you open it on a computer that has `Montserrat` font installed on it, it shows you what its supposed to, but when you open it on a device that `Montserrat` font isn't installed on it, it uses the default font, it's the same thing in production too.

Did I miss something or its Tailwind's new version bug??